# How can I export a single wallet from bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet

On my full node bitcoin wallet, I have a lot of wallets, I can see them with the command dumpwallet "filename" but if I try to export one of those priv keys to another wallet, (blockchain) this New wallet service recognize the public address for this priv key, but not the ammount of bitcoins corresponding to this wallet... Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, what you exported is a private key for an **address**. A wallet is a collection of addresses and their private keys.

The amount that you think is associated with that address is most definitely not the actual amount. What has most likely happened is that you have made a transaction in the past which spent some of those coins and the remainder has ended up in a change address. When you make a transaction, the change Bicoin always goes to a newly generated change address that is part of your wallet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, how can I restore funds from my full node wallet using a private key? It can be only done with another full node wallet?

Comment: You would need to either get all of the private keys from your wallet and import them elsewhere, or copy your wallet file to another Bitcoin Core instance.